# Android how to convert barcode from imageview and print from receipt printer

Tags: android, imageview, barcode, thermal-printer

i manage to printing out the barcode from receipt printer i already convert the imageview to the byte format but the nothing print out from the receipt printer. any suggestion to solve my problem, or there are another way to print out the barcode by receipt printer.

thisis how i convert the imageview to byte and use OutputStream to printing out the barcode.

```
       ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       // barcode data
       String barcode_data = "asdasdasd";
       OutputStream socketOut = null;
       // barcode image
       Bitmap bitmap = null;

       try {

             bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(barcode_data, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, 1000, 1000);
             iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
             bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
             byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
             try {
                    socketOut.write(imageInByte);
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }


             } catch (WriterException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String contents, BarcodeFormat format, int img_width, int img_height) throws WriterException {
    String contentsToEncode = contents;
    if (contentsToEncode == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;
    String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contentsToEncode);
    if (encoding != null) {
        hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
        hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
    }
    MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = writer.encode(contentsToEncode, format, img_width, img_height, hints);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // Unsupported format
        return null;
    }
    int width = result.getWidth();
    int height = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offset = y * width;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bitmap;
}

private static String guessAppropriateEncoding(CharSequence contents) {
    // Very crude at the moment
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++) {
        if (contents.charAt(i) > 0xFF) {
            return "UTF-8";
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: so did you find any solution?